# Auto run a php file in OpenWRT

Tags: php, linux, openwrt

I have one `PHP` file in `lighttpd` web browser that I must reload every 1 minute. Can it run automatically without I open the file in browser.

The `PHP` script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){   

$.getJSON("http://www.exmpl.web.id/data_user.php?jsonp=?", function(data) { 

        // alert(data.user_req);
        if (data.user_req=="1") {
            $.post("../properties/python/on_led.py");
        }
        else if (data.user_req=="2") {
            $.post("../properties/python/off_led.py");
        };
});
</script>
```

Comment: can't you use cron to run it?  what does the script do?

Comment: If your hosting provider/server doesn't support Cron Jobs, there are several online ones.

Comment: @msturdy I've edit my question. The script will read data from my online website and process the data with an action. Meanwhile I should open the file with browser.

Comment: that looks more like `JavaScript` to me.. is it wrapped in a PHP script?

Comment: @rezafahlevi08 Have you looked at Cron Jobs? 'that I must reload every 1 minute' sounds like Cron Job all over.

Comment: @msturdy yes I put it inside php file. I don't know how to run with cron job in OpenWRT

Comment: @dayuloli how to do it in OpenWRT ?

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with OpenWRT, but, at least for now, you can use online ones? It's good to spend some time knowing about it anyways
Here, first steps - google.com/search?q=cron+job+online

Comment: Ok, thank you all for response :)